# Regular expression to replace apostrophe

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all punctuation symbols in given string except " **'** " when it is before text, after and between. For replacing I use `replaceAll()` with regex `"[!.,?;:/]|(?=.['])([^A-Za-z]')"`. But it doesn't work with 5th example. Any ideas how to do it?

Examples:

1. " **'** " -> "  "
2. " **'''** " -> "  "
3. " **text'text** " -> " **text'text** "
4. " **text'** " -> " **text'** "
5. " **'text** " -> " **'text** "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match any of the symbols, or match an apostrophe that is not preceded or succeeded by a word character.

Those are zero-width negative lookbehind assertion and zero-width negative lookahead assertion. Most regex implementations have them, but some do not. You can only put constant-size expressions within them.

`[!.,?;:/]|(?<!\w)'(?!\w)`

Answer (score 0):

The regex provided is syntactically invalid (2 opening parentheses, 1 closing), but that may be a typo.

The suggested solution (regex only):

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])'(?![a-zA-Z])
```

A negative lookbehind checking for absence of text followed by the apostrophe and a negative lookahead again checking for the absence of text.

You might want to adjust the character class defining 'text'.
Demo available [here (Regex 101)](https://regex101.com/r/4DbKea/1).